Data population from Mongo Db
Ive been running my project but my project does not populate the data and instead shows null. The case is where by the data at the backend is not fetched at the fronted . For my case I'm using admission Number as my primary key but when I try to login, the students records are not populated at the home menu. kindly assist me on how can the data be populated once i login with the admission number to the system
this is my studentRecord.js file
   router.get('/:admissionNumber', async (req, res) => {
    res.json({ message: 'This route is accessible.' });



    try {
    const { admissionNumber } = req.params;

    
    const credentials = await Record.findOne({ admissionNumber }).populate('studentRecord');

    if (!credentials || !credentials.studentRecord) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Student data is not available.' });
    }

    res.json({ student: credentials.StudentModel});
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching student data:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Failed to load student data.' });
  }
});

module.exports = router;

and this is my homepage where im trying to fetch the data
 const fetchStudentData = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`https://localhost:3000/api/student/${admissionNumber}`);
      alert(response.data.student);

      if (response.data && response.data.student) {
        const { student } = response.data;
        console.log('Student Data:', student);

        setStudentName(student.studentName);
        setFeeBalance(student.feeBalance);
        setFeeStatement(student.feeStatement);
        setCourse(student.course);
        setAdmissionNumber(student.admissionNumber);
      } else {
        alert("Ooops there is an eerror here");
        setError('Student data is not available.');
        setShowError(true);
        setTimeout(() => setShowError(false), 3000);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching student data:', error);
      alert(error);
      setError('Failed to load student data.');
      setShowError(true);
      setTimeout(() => setShowError(false), 3000);
    }
  }, [admissionNumber]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (admissionNumber) {
      fetchStudentData();
    }
  }, [admissionNumber, fetchStudentData]);

I tried debugging the code but ive not been able to manage solving the issue .
